# Documentation for SKTMapsObject

Tags: skmaps

I've been looking at the [developer site](http://developer.skobbler.com/) and also checked out the official [SKMaps Reference](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.5.0/index.html), but I was unable to find the proper documentation for *SKTMapsObject*.
Is there any documentation you are not telling us about or is it just missing? In any case: Can you please provide documentation for the complete API? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From 2.2 onwards there is an SDKTools library that provides some additional functionality to the SDK (e.g. a download manager & a navigation UI) - a project that lives independent of the SDK, maintained by Scout devs, but open to anyone for modification.

There you'll find also details about SKTMapsObject:
 http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/iosTools

Comment: Sure, I've seen those. However, the word "SKTMapsObject" only occurs 3 times on the whole documentation and what is said about it can't really be considered a proper documentation of the class and its methods. Thanks anyway :)